# Override TextArea ScrollBar with Main Body ScrollBar

Tags: html, css, input, textarea, height

I succeed overriding the textarea scrollbar with the main body scrollbar but I was needed to put an extremely high value to compensate for making the textarea height (atleast) 100%.

The text inside the textarea (...obviously) would by dynamic text typed by the user so I need to **always** compensate for that at the main body scrollbar.

Just in case it wasn't clear the textarea height must be (at least) 100% in any case.

Here is my code :

```css
    body
    {
      background-color:#000;
      border:0;
      margin:0;
      padding:0
    }
    
    textarea
    {
      background-color:#fff;
      border:0;
      box-sizing:border-box;
      display:block;
      height:10000px;
      margin:0;
      outline:none;
      overflow:hidden;
      padding:0;
      position:relative;
      resize:none;
      width:200px
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <textarea>
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      </textarea>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is a live link at liveweave.com:

https://liveweave.com/2OA8uY

I tried `min-height:100%;` but it wasn't working...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving large height value to make text area occupy whole screen you can use `100vh` and `overflow-y: auto` to make it scrollable.

```css
    body
    {
      background-color:#000;
      border:0;
      margin:0;
      padding:0
    }
    
    textarea
    {
      background-color:#fff;
      border:0;
      box-sizing:border-box;
      display:block;
      height:100vh;
      margin:0;
      outline:none;
      overflow:hidden;
      padding:0;
      position:relative;
      resize:none;
      width:50%;
      overflow-y: auto; 
      /* width:200px */
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <textarea>
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      gangina...
      </textarea>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Almost because the scroll is went back to the textarea and I want to be able to scroll it from the main body and not from the textarea scrollbar

Comment: so you want your cursor to anywhere on the screen and when you scroll your textArea should scoll?

Comment: Moreover, I do not want to use a static value for height, I want it always fit the the actual text inside :)

Comment: Exactly, scroller anywhere on the screen and the scroller would be only 1 scroller at the main page that would perfectly fit to the current dynamic text inside the textarea :)